# Writing a variable with the value 0 into a file (Batch)

Tags: batch-file

i'm trying to write an integer to a file using redirection in batch,but i can't seem to do it.All i get is empty lines.

```
set var_1=0
echo %var_1%>output.txt
```

The same happens when i try to write numbers directly without declaring a variable first.
although this is not the case when i use two digit numbers or more.
Any solution to this?

Already tried

```
set var_1=100
set /a var_1=0
echo %var_1%>output.txt
```

Didn't know why i even tried this but i did it and the problem persist.

Thank you in advance.

**Update : * I've already found a solution to this after a lot of searching ***

For those who are interested to the solution and explaination :
http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4668

Answer (score 1):

Problem with a digit directly before the redirector.

try

```
>filename echo 0
```

1>nul redirects standard output to nul (suppresses output)
2>nul redirects standard error to nul (suppresses error messages)

0 is standard input

3..9 similarly affected, nul can be a filename if desired.

Comment: thanks,this solved the problem. echo 0 >output.txt but then the output would be "0 "(zero with a trailing space)

Answer (score 0):

If you try this at the console you see what is going on , you get something like

```
ECHO is on (aan).
```

Which means your 0 is neglected because the console sees it as a kind of null.
Use this instead, the space does the trick

```
echo %var_1% > output.txt
```

Comment: The output i get is "0 " (with a trailing space).This problem is not only limited to "0" but all other integer that is less than two digits